# Just adding useState hook statement causing component to rerender

Tags: reactjs

I have created a basic **create-react-app** and added the below statement

```
const [stateA, setStateA] = useState(false);
```

and I have put a console.log inside my component.
The complete component code is

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [stateA, setStateA] = useState(false);

  console.log("rendered");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It is showing "rendered" twice. Can any one tell why this is happening ?

Comment: React can render your components more than once when running in dev mode, also you might be using the `StrictMode` component which rendering components multiple times to catch side effects inside renders

Answer (score 2):

If you notice `index.js` (as `create-react-app` now uses `React.StrictMode` by default ) file you may have a wrapper called `React.StrictMode` which is responsible for this extra re-render. The wrapper will invoke `render`, `constructor` and other lifecycle methods to detect side effects. So this is expected.

You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Hope this helps!